# MediaStream not releasing something in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, web-audio-api

I'm recording using the AudioWorkletNode method and it seems to be recording ok in all browsers.

When I'm recording the recording icon appears in the tab then goes away when the recording is over.

However, in Safari there is the little speaker icon in the tab (the thing that usually indicates that the tab is making sound) that replaces the microphone icon.

So I think I must not be turning something off.

This is what I do when the recording is finished:

```
// stream is of type MediaStream
if (stream)
  stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
stream = null
```

Stream is created with:

```
stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: options
});
```

Is there something else I need to do to free up all resources?

Answer (score 1):

For turning off everything, the following seems to work. I just got there by trial and error because I couldn't figure out how to get Safari to tell me what it was still holding on to:

```
// stream : MediaStream
// sourceNode : MediaStreamAudioSourceNode
// recorderNode : AudioWorkletNode

const tracks = stream.getTracks();
tracks.forEach((track) => {
  track.stop();
  stream.removeTrack(track)
});
stream = null

sourceNode.disconnect();
sourceNode = undefined

recorderNode.disconnect();
recorderNode = undefined
```